# Treatment of Dasas

Tags: dasa

So this may be a duplicate question, but how were Dasas treated I have heard of laws that condone them as forced manual laborers, but not as property per se. Where are these roles located?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15446/slavery-in-hinduism

Comment: @Hope partly, but more detail is needed.