# How did one become a dasa and is it consented upon

Tags: dharma-shastras, shudra, varnashrama, dharmasutra, dasa

From what I heard a dasa/shudra could consent to servitude. My question is how does one become a Dasa/Dasi?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Manu Smriti 8.415](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201350.html) there are seven ways one can become a Dasa (translated here as slave).

> ध्वजाहृतो भक्तदासो गृहजः क्रीतदत्त्रिमौ ।
>  पैत्रिको दण्डदासश्च
> सप्तैते दासयोनयः ॥ ४१५ ॥
>
> dhvajāhṛto bhaktadāso gṛhajaḥ krītadattrimau |
>  paitriko
> daṇḍadāsaśca saptaite **dāsa**yonayaḥ || 415 ||
>
> There are seven kinds of **slaves**—(1) captured under a banner, (2)
> slave on food, (3) born in the house, (4) bought, (5) presented, (6)
> hereditary, and (7) slave by punishment.—(415)

So, obviously it is approved to acquire and employ Dasas/Dasis.

Medhatithi's commentary on the above verse is as follows:

> The term ‘Dhvajā’ ‘banner’ stands for the chariot;
>
> hence ‘Dhvajinī’ means the army; ho who is captured ‘under the banner’
> is the captive of war, who is made a slave.
>
> “What is stated here,—does it refer to the Kṣatriya,—the meaning being
> that the Kṣatriya made captive in war becomes a slave?”
>
> Not so, we reply; since it is the Śūdra that forms the subject-matter
> of the context; as is clear from the preceding statement—‘it is for
> the purpose of servitude that he has been created.’ What the text
> refers to is the case where the owner of the slave having been
> defeated in battle, the slave is brought over and enslaved by the
> captor.
>
> “as a matter of fact, servitude has been declared to be for all
> Śūdras—when for instance it was asserted that servitude is ‘innate in
> him.’”
>
> It is not so; for in that case there would be a great confusion; as it
> would not be ascertained to whom a certain slave belongs; since all
> the three higher castes would be their masters, to be served by them.
> Hence there would be no restriction. Then again, all that has been
> asserted before (regarding servitude being ‘innate’ in the Śūdra and
> all that) is not of the nature of an injunction. Further, there is the
> declaration that ‘among the castes each of the following shall serve
> the preceding’ (Gautama, 10.66),—by which the Kṣatriya and the Vaiṣhya
> also would have to be regarded as slaves.
>
> All this however is not right. ‘Serving’ is one thing and ‘slavery’ is
> another. Slavery consists in doing servile work, and in not objecting
> to going anywhere he may be sent to; while ‘service’ may consist in
> shampooing the body, guarding the family or property and so forth. All
> this has been dealt with in detail by Nārada.
>
> ‘Slave on food’—he who has accepted slavery for obtaining food.
>
> ‘Born in the house’—i.e., born of a slave-girl.
>
> ‘Bought’—from the former master, for a price.
>
> ‘Presented’—given to one, either through love, or for the purpose of
> acquiring spiritual merit.
>
> ‘Hereditary’—who has belonged to the family through a line of
> ancestors.
>
> “What is the difference between this last and the slave born in the
> house?”
>
> The latter is one born of a slave-girl that may have been acquired by
> the master himself, while the other is hereditary.
>
> ‘Enslaved for punishment’—one who, being incapable of paying the
> king’s fines, is made a slave.
>
> In fact, according to some people, such slaves are possible for the
> other castes also, in view of what has been said regarding the
> propriety of repaying a debt even by manual labour.
>
> But this is not right; as ‘slavery’ is one thing and ‘doing manual
> work’ is something totally different. Nor is the case cited a case of
> ‘punishment,’ whereby it could be included under the present head.
> Then again, when it is said that debts may be repaid ‘by manual work
> also,’ it does not necessarily mean ‘slavery,’ though this also may be
> one kind of ‘work.’
>
> “When the Śūdra works as a slave entirely through considerations of
> his duty, why should there be only seven kinds of slaves?”
>
> There is no force in this objection. Because in his case ‘slavery’ is
> not innate in him; it is purely voluntary wish him; he having recourse
> to it only with a view to acquiring merit. And further, such a slave
> cannot be given away or pledged;—as the bought and house-born slaves
> can. In fact the Śūdra in question is guided by what has been declared
> (under 10.128) regarding the Śūdra ‘imitating the behaviour of the
> virtuous, etc., etc.’; and by this it is clearly implied that slavery
> is not inherent in him; he takes to it only with a view to a definite
> result. Hence there is real ‘slavery’ only when it is involuntary. So
> that if a Śūdra has property of his own and lives upon it, not
> supporting himself by depending upon the Brāhmaṇa and others, he does
> nothing wrong.—(415)

Comment: Can one be freed from hereditary slavery?

Comment: No idea ..but a dasa works for wages so when he finds a better option he might leave the old job @Haridasa

Comment: If a Dasa works for wages he isn't a slave at all, please refer to a verse for this I am increasingly.

Comment: A more correct translation for the word Dasa is not slave but a servant. @Haridasa

Comment: See this --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15448/4732 @Haridasa