# What do theistic hindus think of charvaka philosophy and why?

Tags: philosophy, charvaka

What do theistic hindus think of charvaka philosophy and why? What is the reason that it  was not popular among people ? Is charvaka philosophy considered to be under the roof of sanatan dharma?

Comment: You maybe interested in this question: [What's the response to the Cārvāka thought on animal sacrifice in a yajña?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18105/2995)

Comment: Theistic hindus dismiss carvakism as an atheistic , materialistic and inadequate philosophy. It is not popular because it has been disproved unequivocally. It is not considered to be under the roof of sanatana dharma.

Comment: All we know of Charvaka is through their criticism by theistic schools.