# Why did Yudhishthira give 2,640,000 female slaves to Brahmanas?

Tags: mahabharata, women, sex, yudhisthira

This question is NOT a duplicate of the [above](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/was-slavery-allowed-in-mahabarata-times). My question "Why did Yudhishthira give 2,640,000 female slaves to Brahmanas?" is different from "Was slavery allowed in Mahabarata times?"

---

In the [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02048.htm), Yudhishthira gave 30 female slaves to **each** of 88,000 Brahmanas. 30 multiplied by 88,000 yields 2,640,000. Such a huge number is not unusual, since India has always had a very large population.

> Yudhishthira supporteth eighty-eight thousand Snataka Brahmanas
>   leading domestic lives, giving unto each of them thirty slave-girls.

A "Snataka" is a bachelor who has graduated from Vedic studies, but is not married yet. He is not a Brahmachari.

So, by the mention of "Snataka" and "domestic (householder) lives," the conclusion is that these slave girls were given for sexual intercourse. In other words, they could be *sex slaves.*

On the other hand, it might be prohibited for a Snataka to have sex before marriage. Also, since these were slave-girls, they must be from very low castes, and it is prohibited for a Brahmana to have sex with women of very low castes.

So in that case, these women were just maids and servants.

Is there a commentary that explains this verse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was slavery allowed in Mahabarata times?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11356/was-slavery-allowed-in-mahabarata-times)

Comment: @CR241 No it is NOT a duplicate. I'm asking WHY Yudhishtira gave those slaves to Brahmanas and not "Why was slavery allowed in Mahabharata times?"

Comment: I can get reference

Comment: I believe not it is a sin to do sexual acts on a slave.